# View That Appears When Start Typing, iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

What's the best way to implement this animation, using Swift:

New view slides immediately after user starts typing. 
New view has labels that are being updated.

Do I really need to create a new view programmatically? I feel like there should be a standard UIKit solution.

[image]

Comment: You are looking for [Input Accessory View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621119-inputaccessoryview)

Comment: @adev you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One of the many approaches could be to put a UIView below your main
>   view that contains the TextField.
>
> Now the view that you want to appear when user starts typing should
>   have initial height set to 0 in storyboard.
>
> Make an outlet for that height constraint to your ViewController. As
>   the user starts typing, you could change the height constraint to
>   whatever height you want and put all that code inside a UIView
>   animation block, to animate.

Something like:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: { () -> Void in

            self.heightCons.constant = 100
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()


        }, completion: nil)
```

You could also explore various animation options that are available.

Comment: for your solution, I have 2 questions: 
1. Label with initial $ (on light green field) will have to be moved as well? after we start typing. 
2. How to make UISegmentedController to appear with animation? 
Thank you Umar.

Comment: @Evgeny, if you use constraints you won't have to move that label, because due to the use of constraints, once you add some height to the  label below, the one on top would be pushed upwards (if you don't set height of the label above otherwise it would be crushed).

You can use these for segment control. https://github.com/gmarm/BetterSegmentedControl
Also accept the answer if it helped !